# Does a sequence whose subsequences converge to the same limit converge to the same limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does a sequence whose subsequences converge to the same limit converge to the same limit? 
There is a theorem which says that if a sequence is convergent then all of its subsequences converge to the same limit. This is however only an implication and so does not necessarily have to be true. Thus, my question is: 
If this should be the case, which is fairly intuitive. is there a theorem/axiom which supports the statement?

Comment: Take two mutually exclusive completely exhaustive sub sequences, for.eg a sub-sequence of $a_i$ where $i$ is even and other where $i$ is odd, if both of them converge to same limit all the terms of the sequence do

Answer (score 2):

HINT: A sequence is one of its subsequences.